# Probability of a 100 year-old dying in the next 3 years

Tags: probability

Given the following death-probabilities (defined as probability of dying in the next year from the given age), is the probability of a 100-year-old dying by age 103 the sum of those probabilities, i.e. = 1.12? If so, how would one state the odds of dying by age 103 having achieved age 100?  Thanks.

```
Age   Death Probability
---   -----------------
100   .36
101   .37
102   .39
```

Comment: Subtraction and multiplication are involved

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the probability that he *does not* die in the next three years and subtract that probability from 1.

Comment: Of course! Thank you!